# I am unable to send email to multiple recipients while looping over a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, email

I am trying to loop over a dataframe while sending an email and getting an error. Following is my code. The idea is to send custom emails to the email_list comprising respective First Name and Score.

```
email_list = [abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com, ghi@gmail.com]

email['from'] = 'xyz'
email['subject'] = 'Corporate Rating Quiz'

for recipient in email_list:
    email['To'] = recipient
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        email.set_content(html.substitute({'name' : row['First Name'], 'score' : row['Score']}))
        with smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com',port=587) as smtp:
            smtp.ehlo()
            smtp.starttls()
            smtp.login('*@gmail.com','*')
            smtp.send_message(email)
            del email['To']
            print('all done!')
```

Error received is: smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {} and email ends up only being sent to first recipient.

I've looked around a lot and cant find any solution for this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your dataframe, that is why could you try this one:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

email_list = ["abc@gmail.com","def@gmail.com","ghi@gmail.com"]

email = MIMEMultipart()
email['from'] = 'xyz@gmail.com'
email['subject'] = 'Corporate Rating Quiz'

for recipient in email_list:
    email['To'] = recipient
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        email.set_content(html.substitute({'name' : row['First Name'], 'score' : row['Score']}))
        with smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com',port=587) as smtp:
            smtp.ehlo()
            smtp.starttls()
            smtp.login('*@gmail.com','*')
            smtp.send_message(email)
            email['To']= ""
            print('all done!')
```